# How can I compute a dual norm?

Tags: r, function, math, mathematical-optimization

Suppose I have a norm `||x||`. Is there an R function or method that allows me to calculate the dual norm

```
||y||_* = \max_{x} x^Ty : ||x|| ≤ 1
```

?

My initial thought is that this falls under a constrained optimization problem, so I imagine there's some useful packages to solve this, but I haven't been able to formulate how to do this.

Comment: `nloptr`, `alabama` handle nonlinear inequality constraints (see the [Optimization task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html)

Comment: I don't understand your notation.  Is `x^T` "x to the power T" or "x transpose"?  What spaces do `x` and `y` live in?

Comment: @user2554330 it is transpose, say, to calculate the inner product of two vectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Analytical Dual Norm Solution

There indeed exists an analytical dual norm representation (see [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm))

[image]
so we can code the dual norm function like below. It should be noted that, the code below gives a scalar value of dual norm only, rather than the solution of `z` that enables the supremum (as `$par` in the outcome of `dual_norm_numeric`.

```
dual_norm_analytic <- function(x, p) {
    if (p < 1) {
        stop("Invalide value of p: Shouldn be >= 1!")
    }
    if (p == 1) {
        return(max(abs(x)))
    }
    if (is.infinite(p)) {
        return(sum(abs(x)))
    }
    q <- 1 / (1 - 1 / p)
    sum(abs(x)^q)^(1 / q)
}
```

with input data

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 10
x <- rnorm(n, 5)
```

we will obtain that

```
> dual_norm_analytic(x, 1)
[1] 7.404653

> dual_norm_analytic(x, 2)
[1] 17.3279

> dual_norm_analytic(x, 3)
[1] 25.15705
```

---

## Numerical Solution by `fmincon` Optimization

If you are working with a vector `x` (rather than a matrix, since matrix norm would be a different story, but you might be able to try out in a similar way as shown in a following code), probably you can try `fmincon` from the `pracma` package and define a custom dual norm function, e.g.,

```
library(pracma)
dual_norm_numeric <- function(x, p) {
    if (p < 1) {
        stop("Invalide value of p: Shouldn be >= 1!")
    }
    if (p == 1) {
        val <- max(abs(x))
        sign(x[abs(x) == max(abs(x))])
        return(list(value = val, par = sign(x[abs(x) == val]) * (abs(x) == val)))
    }
    if (is.infinite(p)) {
        return(list(value = sum(abs(x)), par = sign(x)))
    }
    constr <- \(y) sum(abs(y)^p)^(1 / p) - 1
    fobj <- \(y) -sum(x * y)
    out <- fmincon(x * 0, fobj, hin = constr)
    list(value = -out$value, par = out$par)
}
```

## Output (Example)

Given `x` as below

```
> set.seed(0)

> n <- 10

> x <- rnorm(n, 5)

> set.seed(0)

> n <- 10

> x <- rnorm(n,5)
```

and you will see

```
> dual_norm_numeric(x, 1)
$value
[1] 7.404653

$par
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1


> dual_norm_numeric(x, 2)
$value
[1] 17.3279

$par
 [1] 0.3614374 0.2697252 0.3652950 0.3619841 0.3124811 0.1996814 0.2349643
 [8] 0.2715437 0.2882193 0.4273251


> dual_norm_numeric(x, 3)
$value
[1] 25.15705

$par
 [1] 0.4989528 0.4310259 0.5016088 0.4993309 0.4639326 0.3708614 0.4022939
 [8] 0.4324763 0.4455585 0.5425285
```

Comment: Seems to work well. However, when I try to use the L1 norm (p=1) I get the following error: `Error in chol.default(ZHZ) : the leading minor of order 10 is not positive`

Comment: @Tom yes, that is a boundary case for condition `p>=1`, see my update